# using axios post from react to django rest framework got 400 ( bad request) when posting objects contains empty strings

Tags: django, reactjs, post, axios, bad-request

I don't get it why this is happening
as long as i post an object with an empty string value in it will cause an error
and the code snippet is the function that I called for posting values

### result from posting with empty string:

https://i.ibb.co/jfhcQY8/1.png

### post with arbitrary values:

https://i.ibb.co/CtZ2CKB/2.png

```
    addToServer(e) {
        console.log("item: " + this._input.value)
        if (this._input.value !== "") {
            var newItem = {
                "title": this._input.value,
                "content": "", //===>if it's empty string it will get a 400 error, however if i change to any non empty value, it will work
                "complete": false,
            };
            console.log("item: " + newItem.title)
            console.log(newItem)
            axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/todo/", newItem)
            .then(res => this.axiosGet())
            .catch( err => console.log(err))
        }

        this._input.value = "";
        this._input.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: Does your server implement validation for case that content is empty ?

Comment: I don't know, how can I check if the backend need validations?

Comment: If you did not implement this kind of validation, maybe your framework you used did.

Comment: please show the view called from `http://localhost:8000/api/todo/`